# Gunicorn: No module named 'app' on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

Completely new to AWS. Trying to install Flask on an EC2 instance using gunicorn.

I have a simple app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

When using gunicorn in venv it is not showing any error but when creating a service in systemd it is throwing this error:

> File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 983, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' [2022-08-24 15:49:19 +0000]
> [13336] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13336) [2022-08-24 15:49:19 +0000]
> [13333] [INFO] Shutting down: Master [2022-08-24 15:49:19 +0000]
> [13333] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

I tried several stuff: changing localhost, changing port, exposing port in security group to allow any connection, tried to add pythonpath to gunicorn, using specific path for the app:app... with no luck.

here is the service file i am using:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance for a simple hello world app
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/helloworld
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/helloworld/venv/bin/gunicorn --pythonpath /home/ec2-user/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages -b lo$
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

App.py is located in /home/ec2-user/helloworld/

I believe it is a path conflict?

Comment: are you deploying with Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @AudioBaton no direct ssh access to the instance